# ElasticSearch snapshot/backup doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, backup, snapshot

My ES snapshot doesn't work or looks empty.

First, I have done this on my Ubuntu server:

1.create a directory for backups

```
mkdir /home/admin/dumps/elasticsearch
```

2.set this directory to elastissearch.yml for snapshots

```
path.repo: ["/home/admin/dumps/elasticsearch"]
```

3.setup the snapshot repository location

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/backup' -d '{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/home/admin/dumps/elasticsearch",
    "compress": true
  }
}'
```

Then, I can run a snapshot:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_snapshot/backup/elasticsearch_snapshot?wait_for_completion=true
```

Response:

> {"snapshot":{"snapshot":"elasticsearch_snapshot","version_id":2030099,"version":"2.3.0","indices":["references"],"state":"SUCCESS","start_time":"2016-04-08T08:45:30.525Z","start_time_in_millis":1460105130525,"end_time":"2016-04-08T08:45:30.779Z","end_time_in_millis":1460105130779,"duration_in_millis":254,"failures":[],"shards":{"total":15,"failed":0,"successful":15}}}

I also created a cronjob to backup ElasticSearch at 5:35 each day:

```
35 5 * * * curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/backup/elasticsearch.$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d)?wait_for_completion=true"
```

Well, when I go to my dumps/elasticsearch folder, I got that:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  256 Apr  8 10:45 index drwxr-xr-x 5 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 Apr  8 05:35 indices
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  121 Apr  1 05:35 meta-elasticsearch.2016-04-01.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  121 Apr  2 05:35 meta-elasticsearch.2016-04-02.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  121 Apr  3 05:35 meta-elasticsearch.2016-04-03.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  121 Apr  4 05:35 meta-elasticsearch.2016-04-04.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  121 Apr  5 05:35 meta-elasticsearch.2016-04-05.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  121 Apr  6 05:35 meta-elasticsearch.2016-04-06.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  121 Apr  7 05:35 meta-elasticsearch.2016-04-07.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  121 Apr  8 05:35 meta-elasticsearch.2016-04-08.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  213 Apr  1 05:35 snap-elasticsearch.2016-04-01.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  213 Apr  2 05:35 snap-elasticsearch.2016-04-02.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  213 Apr  3 05:35 snap-elasticsearch.2016-04-03.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  212 Apr  4 05:35 snap-elasticsearch.2016-04-04.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  213 Apr  5 05:35 snap-elasticsearch.2016-04-05.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  213 Apr  6 05:35 snap-elasticsearch.2016-04-06.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  213 Apr  7 05:35 snap-elasticsearch.2016-04-07.dat
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  217 Apr  8 05:35 snap-elasticsearch.2016-04-08.dat

Cron snapshots are there but all data seems empty !
What did I miss ?

Comment: What happens when you try restoring from one of the snapshots?

Comment: OK. Seems it worked ! `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/backup/elasticsearch.2016-04-11/_restore'` I'm very surprised cos' It was restored immediatly... and I have 1.5M documents?! (I made an entire index delete just before)

Comment: My entire directory size seems to be 691M - So looks OK.

Comment: Backups are incremental. If you have little traffic, I guess the backups after the first are pretty much immediate. Also, backups on `fs` should be quite fast anyway. I switch to S3 (was-cloud plugin) and it is already pretty fast.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for this feedback Eric !

Comment: It seems to be you didn't have an issue. the place you checked was creating a small file with .dat extension. All the real files are created at the location in the same directory with the name of "indices" folder name.

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch snapshot only metadata of snapshots are stored on root level path.
All indices backup actual data is stored under `/indices` folder in root path.

If you look inside `/indices` folder, you will see your cluster data